# Helm chart ingress.yaml return error error nil pointer evaluating interface

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Following a task on using helm chart, but was not able to install ingress.yaml. It is complaining about a class. The error is pasted below. Is there anything am missing here?

ingress/templates/ingress.yaml:6:43: executing "ingress/templates/ingress.yaml" at <.Values.ingress.annotations.class>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.class

The code for the ingress.yaml is below :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.ingress.name }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {{ .Values.ingress.annotations.class }}
spec:
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                 name: {{ .backend.service.name }}
                 port:
                    number: {{ .backend.service.port.number }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

The values in the values.yaml is :

```
ingress:
      name: ingress-service
      replicaCount: 1
      annotations: 
        class: nginx
      hosts:
        - host: chart-example.local
          paths: 
            - path: /
              backend:
                  service:
                     name: ServiceName
                     port:
                        number: 8080
```

Comment: if you are still facing an issue after changing to `.backend.service.port.number`, then problem appears to be some other place that is not shown in the question. Note that the error line number is not always accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.ingress.name }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {{ .Values.ingress.annotations.class }}
spec:
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                 name: {{ .backend.service.name }}
                 port:
                    number: {{ .backend.service.port }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you posted here as the answer is not properly formatted

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: But I do not see any difference in your code and mine. I have pasted it exactly as well, so the same issue. Thanks